# How to prevent sync.Pool creating two instances

Tags: go, goroutine

I am implementing a TCP Connection pool for logging to fluent-bit, here's the code

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sync"
)

type FluentConnectionPool struct {
    sync.Mutex
    pool          *sync.Pool
}

func (fl *FluentConnectionPool) Log(message string) {
    fl.Lock()
    defer fl.Unlock()

    conn := fl.pool.Get().(*net.TCPConn)
    defer fl.pool.Put(conn)

    fmt.Printf("using: %v\n", conn.LocalAddr())

    if _, err := conn.Write([]byte(message)) ; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func (fl *FluentConnectionPool) Close() {
    conn := fl.pool.Get().(*net.TCPConn)
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Closing: %v\n", conn.LocalAddr())
}

func New(address string) (*FluentConnectionPool, error) {
    fluentAddress, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", address)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pool := &sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        connection, _ := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, fluentAddress)
        return connection
    }}

    return &FluentConnectionPool{
        pool:          pool,
    }, nil
}
```

when I test the code like this

```golang
import "time"

func main() {
    pool, _ := New("localhost:5170")
    defer pool.Close()

    for i := 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
        go func() {
               pool.Log(`{"data": {"name": "name here"}}`)
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

the output is like this

```
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43990
using: 127.0.0.1:43994
Closing: 127.0.0.1:43994
```

I don't understand why the connection create twice (43990 & 43994) even though I have locked the function, so the connection on 43990 remains open, could you please explain why did this happened?

Thank You!

Comment: What's the mutex for? It looks like it's only locking access to the `Pool`, which is already thread-safe, as you can tell by it being in the `sync` package and its [clear documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool).

Comment: An item stored in a sync.Pool may be automatically removed.  The second connection is created after the first connection is automatically removed.  The code in `FluentConnectionPool.Close` assumes that the pool has at most one connection. The lock ensures that there's no more than one connection in the pool.  Why use the pool instead of a field to hold the connection?

Comment: This also looks like a complete misuse of `sync.Pool`, which is an *object pool*, not a *connection pool*. The implementation assumes that values that are *in* the pool are not in use and can be removed at any time. Its purpose is not to pool active connections; its purpose is to pool objects which may be expensive to instantiate.

Comment: It is not appropriate to store connections in a sync.Pool because there's no guarantee when an evicted connection's Close method will be called or if the method will be called at all.

Comment: Yep, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This from the `Pool` docs might explain the behaviour:

> Any item stored in the Pool may be removed automatically at any time without notification. If the Pool holds the only reference when this happens, the item might be deallocated.

It is likely that the pool removed the connection you used.